# Call python script from python script and get response

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest

my problem is about calling a python script from another python script and get a response asynchronously.
The situation is the following: script1.py starts and calls ONE TIME script2.py which runs in a loop waiting for some kind of http traffic (it's a proxy). Script1.py continues to make http requests iteratively and script2.py must capture the responses and pass them back to script1.py.
Pseudo code:

```
#script1.py

call script2.py
for i in something:
    httprequests
    receive variable httpresponses(str) from script2.py
```

I see some posts about calling a script from python and pass values to that script but nothing about getting values from it. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: If script1.py needs values from script2.py and those values can only be generated after full script2.py has executed, then how can the call be asynchronous? Did I get your question?

Comment: Why not write a function in script2 and import it to script1 and use?

Comment: use sockets on localhost with user-defined messages. http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-programming-tutorial/